# IOS Multi value setting dynamic values

Tags: ios, settings

I'm attempting to make the values in a .plist Multi Value dynamic. Specifically, I want to download a list of options from a web site and populate the values with the returned data. I have read a couple of posts stating that changing the app bundle during runtime is impossible. Is it not possible to make the values refer to a data source outside the app bundle, for example if I put the alternatives in NSUserDefaults and read from there?

If this is totally out of the question, what alternatives are there?

Comment: Why not just copy the plist to the Documents or Library directory upon first startup and modify that plist?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is copy the plist into a hidden folder in the documents directory and work with that copy

If the file does not exist, copy it entirely, and if it does, do some merging or overwrite completely, whatever fits your needs

Working with NSUserDefaults is also a possibility